# Only the last item has the text in an ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, asynchronous

I'm having a hard time solving this problem.
Here's the code:

```js
const postBox = document.querySelector('#posts')

const getUser = function(id, val) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `/api/user/${id}`,
    success: function(response) {
      val.innerHTML = `Posted by: ${response.username}`
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
}

const getPosts = () => {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/posts/',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      response.forEach(el => {
        postBox.innerHTML += `
          <div class="card mb-2">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">${el.title}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">${el.body}</p> 
                  <p class="card-text">${el.date}</p>              
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  <p class="card-text" id='author${el.id}'></p>
              </div>
          </div>
        `
        const authorBox = document.querySelector(`#author${el.id}`)
        console.log(authorBox)
        getUser(el.author, authorBox)
      })
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('error')
    },
  })
}

getPosts()
```

Only the last item has the "Posted by author"
I can't seem to figure out why only the last item has it. Even when I inspect it, it has the "Posted by author" inner html and inner text but it's not showing it.

here's the output:

Test 1

Test 1

2021-07-12

Test 2

Test 2

2021-07-12

Test 3

Test 3

2021-07-12

Test 4

Test 4

2021-07-12

Posted by: kyrios

How do I make sure that all of the authorBox has their inner html changed?

(edit)

This is the response from /api/posts/

```
Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: 1, title: "Test 1", date: "2021-07-12", … }
​
1: Object { id: 2, title: "Test 2", date: "2021-07-12", … }
​
2: Object { id: 3, title: "Test 3", date: "2021-07-12", … }
​
3: Object { id: 4, title: "Test 4", date: "2021-07-12", … }
​
length: 4
```

each object is

```
author: 1
​​
body: "Test 1"
​​
category: 1
​​
date: "2021-07-12"
​​
id: 1
​​
image: null
​​
title: "Test 1"
```

I'm using the django rest framework generics ListViewApi.

Comment: This is very inefficient. It creates additional call and query for every post. Why aren't you including author information in the `/api/posts/` response?

Comment: Is el.id duplicated?

Comment: I'm using the generics ListViewSet from django rest framework and since it's a foreignkey it just returns the id of the author, since js can't see in my database I don't know how to reference the author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for wasting the time of some of the people who is kind enough to answer. My original goal was just so I can reference the username of the author instead of the primary key. I thought that Django rest framework didn't have a way, until I came across the Serializer Relations, I'm embarrassed to say that I asked the wrong question in the first place where I should have just ask about the problem to begin with instead of a roundabout way. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to select the author using the `` $(`#author${el.id}`).val() `` instead of

`` document.querySelector(`#author${el.id}`) ``

Comment: The OP did not include jQuery in the tag list, it may not be desirable. However you are correct that getting the `.value` is necessary before calling `getUser()`.

Comment: It just returns <empty string>

Comment: Can you post the response from /api/posts. This will help to debug the issue.